# Nodejs on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, node.js

I have just installed Nodejs on a server running Windows Server 2003 R2.
I ran the demo server configured to use `1337` port & I am able to access the HTTP server locally on server machine. But Nodejs HTTP server is not accessible from the other computers in the network.

What should be the problem for this?  Security settings (open ports related)?

Advance Thanks!

Comment: It's possibly due to the firewall not allowing remote communication on the port. Though, if the "*demo*" you mentioned is the [example on the homepage](http://nodejs.org/), you'll need to `.listen()` with a remote-facing IP address or [just specify the `port`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) -- "*If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections directed to any IPv4 address (`INADDR_ANY`).*"

Comment: Have you tried adding that port to the Windows Firewall exceptions list?

Answer (score 1):

Your firewall settings blocks incoming requests on port **`1337`** if its not configured. You may have do chances in firewall settings, you need to add firewall inbound rule on this port to allow access to it.

Otherwise you may try changing the port to `8080` or `8000` which firewall mostly allows. (updated as per the suggestions form [adam-stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1502081/adam-stanley))

If you want to look how to add port to firewall on Windows, here is the [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783180.aspx)

Comment: yeah, suggest changing the port to something else (e.g. 8000 or 8080).